# bookmarklet css stylesheet inject

Tags: css, bookmarklet

I want to insert a css stylesheet with bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function(){var%20s=document.createElement('link');s.setAttribute('href','http://localhost/~simha/new.css');s.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');s.setAttribute('type','text/css');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);alert('Stylesheet%20injected!');})();
```

when deminified

```
javascript: (function () {
    var s = document.createElement('link');
    s.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost/~simha/new.css');
    s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    alert('Stylesheet injected!');
})();
```

I made this bookmarklet and ran, it added the link element in the head of the html, with the css href also. BUt the css rules in the new.css didnt apply.  There are not changes made to the web page.

Comment: This could have something to do with cross site scripting. Since you serve the file as local file. Have you tried to serve the file from localhost or another server?

Comment: i have changed the ref of the css to localhost, still not working, I edited my question

Comment: Now I know what you mean. Did you try to load the css with an ajax request? (jQuery.getScript())

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the CSP rules are common on websites, it is better to just write the style in the bookmarklet itself. See a [live example here](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQCgZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQgJSoN4B02qEBuAhgE6oDOqAvKgCZIwQC2AplHAHQxlslw2AUQA2bdpxABySnACeYqRnyFClLgihQ2ZACpsAHnFqpcwAEZJ6cnKnMkYAawDmZJNHoBaGEhFIyAFyofPSoAL5mKqqMzBLcABb89FwkAA6pHPQAwvEIIvQglMpQYRiYANzAQA)

```
(function () {
    var s = document.createElement('style')
    s.innerText = "body { background-color: red }"
    document.head.appendChild(s)
})();
```